# Making my elements appear in vertically aligned rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to replicate this website: 
https://t.gyazo.com/teams/leovegas/dcfef17a5c89c99b7b59e88f997e7cfe.mp4

( might have to refresh the page to get GIF to work)

I have everything setup that I want using flexbox so that it sizes change when the browser window does, I just need to make these three sections appear in three vertical rows from left to right when the screen size is larger then 710px.

I have tried to use flex-direction: row; and flex-direction: column; but they don't seem to want to work! Even when I use justify content, or align items the three sections break off and arrange themselves in odd ways. I think its some code of mine that is messing with it but I cannot figure it out!

https://repl.it/@GunarsAuskaps/flexbox-mobile-first-starter-1

here is my code for anyone that wants to look it over.

I want the three columns to be arranged from left to right, in their own separate up-down columns, separated evenly, and shrink and grow with flex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just reviewed the code structure. There's no code issue. You need to add the `clear: both;` class in `main` element. I have tried and it's working.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 710px) {
  main {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

Here is the solution:

https://codepen.io/ydhiman20/pen/LomeKG

Comment: @GunarsAuskaps I hope it will help you!

Comment: Amazing! Worked perfectly, thank you so much for the help!